# How to use FormatCurrency with a text field filled with decimal numbers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, currency

I have a data extension with decimal numbers (seperated by comma) and formatted as text (changeable).

Now I want to use that data and put it with `FormatCurrency()` into the right shape for the countries.

e.g. 50,00 --> culturecode de_AT € 50,00

I tried different things, but failed.

I tried to convert a decimal number (seperated by comma) into the correct curreny:

```
%%[

var @priceStr, @priceFormatted
set @priceStr = "20,50" /* for testing */
set @priceFormatted = formatCurrency(@priceStr,"de-AT") 

]%%
```

the result is `€ 2.050,00`. I was hoping for `€ 20,50`.

Then I tried to reference directly to the data extension:

```
set @priceFormatted = FormatCurrency(@priceStr,"de-AT")
```

The error message:

> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatCurrency function call. The input value () cannot be formatted as a number. The first parameter value for a FormatNumber call must be a numeric type supported by the requested format. Value: Format: C

I get that message by using textfields, decimals or numbers in the data extension.

---

update:
My source data field from a data extension: p3_Product1_Preis_Text1 (formatted as text) e.g. 17,99

My goal: convert that data into the currency format of the specific country by using the culture-code

My approach:
var @priceStr, @priceFormatted /generate new var´s
set @priceStr = replace(@p3_Product1_Preis_Text1,',','.') / replace the comma by a dot to make it fittable for the cuurency function
set @priceFormatted = FormatNumber(@priceStr,"C","de-DE") / using the function

The error message: 
the replace-function is working. Thanks! Now when I´m connecting the AMP with the real data extension I´m still getting that error message: "The error message: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatCurrency function call. The input value () cannot be formatted as a number. The first parameter value for a FormatNumber call must be a numeric type supported by the requested format. Value: Format: C

I get that message by using textfields, decimals or numbers in the data extension.

Thanks in advance!

----Update----

Hi Johannes, sorry but I´m kind of new in the Amp-world.

With your last answer I tried that in the initialization:

set @P3_Product1_Preis_Text1= lookup(@source,"P3_Product1_Preis_Text1","countrylangkey",@countrylangkey)
set @priceStr = lookup(@source,"P3_Product1_Preis_Text1","countrylangkey",@countrylangkey)
var @priceStr2
set @priceStr2 = Replace(@priceStr,',','.')

I filled that in the content block: %%=FormatCurrency(@priceStr2,"fr_FR")=%%

and received the error message: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatCurrency function call. See inner exception for details.
Function Call: FormatCurrency(@priceStr2,"fr_FR")

An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatCurrency function call. The input value () cannot be formatted as a number. The first parameter value for a FormatNumber call must be a numeric type supported by the requested format.
 Value: 
 Format: C

What am I doing wrong? :-(

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far? That way it is easy for us to identify any possible issue(s) with that implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this on a cloudpage.

```
%%=FormatCurrency("50,00","de_AT")=%%<br>
%%=FormatCurrency("50,00","fr_FR")=%%
<br>

<br>
%%=FormatCurrency(50.00,"de_AT")=%%<br>
%%=FormatCurrency(50.00,"fr_FR")=%%
```

Result

[image]

I believe you did something wrong. maybe a typical mistake like this one   `%%=FormatCurrency(50,00,"fr_FR")=%%` In this case the comma will be used to seperate the parameters of the function and will not be used for the currecy value.

If you have troubles with , and . inside the variable use the AMP function replace.

```
%%=Replace(@priceStr,',','.')=%%
```

Code Example 2:

```
%%[
var @priceStr, @priceStr2
set @priceStr = "20,50"
set @priceStr2 = Replace(@priceStr,',','.')
]%%

%%=v(@priceStr)=%%
%%=v(@priceStr2)=%%
<br><br>
%%=FormatCurrency(@priceStr,"fr_FR")=%%<br>
%%=FormatCurrency(@priceStr,"de_AT")=%%<br>
<br><br>
%%=FormatCurrency(@priceStr2,"fr_FR")=%%<br>
%%=FormatCurrency(@priceStr2,"de_AT")=%%<br>
```

Result 2:

[image]

When you want to have this value while Sending you should request it with a LookUp or directly from the DataExtension (if you are sending from it).
For reference of LookUp: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm

Comment: the replace-function is working. Thanks! Now when I´m connecting the AMP with the real data extension I´m still getting that error message: "The error message: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatCurrency function call. The input value () cannot be formatted as a number. The first parameter value for a FormatNumber call must be a numeric type supported by the requested format. Value: Format: C I get that message by using textfields, decimals or numbers in the data extension." I ´tried it with decimal, text and number formatted fields....

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the complete stuff. Where does the value come from? What type of field is it? How do you fill the variable? Why does it show FormatNumber error when you use formatCurrency? Just some stuff we don’t know but which would help us a lot understanding your case.

Comment: I dont know why you are using FormatNumber at all. I have edited my above answer to show you how i would do it.

Comment: Hi Johannes, sorry but I´m kind of new in the Amp-world.

Comment: I have an update above